# Stale Element reference error on finding the element -> when navigates back to previous page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My WebDriver script is simply finding elements on the page 1(Product display page) and clicking on 1st element to see if its working, then navigates back to Product display page.

It throws Stale Element Reference error and does not click the second element on the page, says element is not attached to the page.

Code is :

```
public class EcommerceSearchResult {

public static WebDriver driver ;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'search')]"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("iphone"+"\n");
    List<WebElement>  gridrow 
    = driver.findElements
    (By.xpath(".//*[@id='grid_view_products_page_container']/div/div"));        
    int count = gridrow.size();
    System.out.print(count);
        for(int i = 0 ; i<count ; i++)
        { 
            List<WebElement> listingelementinloop = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='grid_view_products_page_container']/div/div")); 
            System.out.println(gridrow.get(i).getText());   
            listingelementinloop.get(i).click();
            driver.navigate().back();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you need to replace following line:

```
System.out.println(gridrow.get(i).getText());
```

With

```
System.out.println(listingelementinloop.get(i).getText());
```

As, elements in the **gridrow** list will become stale once you click on 'Back' button of browser.

Alternatively, following is another way of performing the same task:

```
public static WebDriver driver ;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'search')]"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("iphone"+"\n");
    List<WebElement>  gridrow  
    = driver.findElements
    (By.xpath(".//*[@id='grid_view_products_page_container']/div/div"));        
    int count = gridrow.size();
    System.out.print(count);
    for(int i = 1 ; i<=count ; i++)
        { 
            WebElement element =
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='grid_view_products_page_container']/div/div[" + i + "]")); 
            System.out.println(element.getText());   
            element.click();
            driver.navigate().back();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

}


}
```

Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are looping through a collection of elements that you collected from the page. Once you leave that page or reload it, the element references you were storing become stale, thus the error. One way to get around this is to use an index into the collection and loop over that. I've rewritten your code to make use of functions to take care of repeated actions. I've tested this code and it works.

Part of `main`

```
driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");
Search("iphone");
for (int i = 0; i < GetProductCount(); i++)
{
    ClickProduct(i);
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

and supporting functions

```
public void Search(String searchTerm)
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Search Products']")).sendKeys(searchTerm + "\n");
}

public void ClickProduct(int index)
{
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h2 > a")).get(index).click();
}

public int GetProductCount()
{
    return driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h2 > a")).size();
}
```

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution code for your problem.Tested it in my machine and attached console screenshot.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class EcommerceSearchResult {

   public static WebDriver driver ;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'search')]"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("iphone"+"\n");
    List<WebElement>  gridrow = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='grid_view_products_page_container']/div/div"));        
    int count = gridrow.size();
    System.out.print(count+"\n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i<count ; i++)
    { 
        WebElement listingelementinloop = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='grid_view_products_page_container']/div/div["+(i+1)+"]")); 
        System.out.println(listingelementinloop.getText());
        listingelementinloop.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/a")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("products-page/product-category"));
        driver.navigate().back();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("iphone | Search Results | ONLINE STORE"));
    }
    }
    }
```

[image]